# How to create App Catalog Site through Code?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

I am looking for a way to create Sharepoint AppCatalog on Office 365 through C# or Powershell. I am not able to find Client Tenant API which does that. I do see Create Site using the Tenant API  but it says that template is not found when i use "APPCATALOG#0"

```
SiteCreationProperties template = new SiteCreationProperties()
        {
            Url = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/AppCatalog1",
            Owner = "andrew@test.onmicrosoft.com",
            Title = "AppCatalog",
            Template = "APPCATALOG#0",
            StorageMaximumLevel = 1000, 
            UserCodeMaximumLevel =100

        };
  SpoOperation op = tenant.CreateSite(template);
        adminContext.Load(tenant);
        adminContext.Load(op, i => i.IsComplete);
        adminContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Any Pointers would be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Well it is probably not good news but better than no news at all. Been researching the topic for quite a while and my conclusion is that you can't create an app catalog in SPO. You can try the PowerShell Get-SPOWebTemplate to check what site templates you can use when creating new sites.